# Does spring junit rollback by default?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I'm testing my DAO layer using Spring and Junit. This is my test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:application-context-test.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestEmployeeDAO {

@Autowired
private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

@Test
@Transactional
public void testInsertEmployee(){
    Employee employee = new Employee("Abdel Karim");
    employeeDAO.insert(employee);
    .
    .
    . 
    }
}
}
```

But when i execute the test and i check my database i find that no row is inserted, and no exception is thrown. I don't understand why, does the default behaviour of Spring (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner) is to rollback the transaction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to check whether the data is inserted you need to do it inside the test method.. once the method is ran, spring will rollback the changes..

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by default rollback is true. To switch it off use:

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback(false)
public void testInsertEmployee(){
    Employee employee = new Employee("Abdel Karim");
    employeeDAO.insert(employee);
}
```